# Sqlite subselect much faster than distinct + order by

Tags: optimization, sqlite

I'm confused by the drastically different running times of the following two queries that produce identical output.  The queries are running on Sqlite 3.7.9, on a table with about 4.5 million rows, and each produce ~50 rows of results.

Here are the queries:

```
% echo "SELECT DISTINCT acolumn FROM atable ORDER BY acolumn;" | time sqlite3 mydb
sqlite3 mydb  8.87s user 15.06s system 99% cpu 23.980 total


% echo "SELECT acolumn FROM (SELECT DISTINCT acolumn FROM atable) ORDER BY acolumn;" | time sqlite3 options
sqlite3 mydb  1.15s user 0.10s system 98% cpu 1.267 total
```

Shouldn't the performance of the two queries be closer?  I understand that it may be the case that the query planner is performing the "sort" and "distinct" operations in different orders, but if so, does it need to?  Or should it be able to figure out how to do it fastest?

**Edit**: as requested here is the output of the "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN" command for each query.

For the first (monolithic) query:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE atable (~1000000 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

For the second (subquery) query:

```
1|0|0|SCAN TABLE atable (~1000000 rows)
1|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
0|0|0|SCAN SUBQUERY 1 (~1000000 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Comment: Please show the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for both queries.

Comment: intresting, did you run queries several times? in different order? I want to repeat your experiments, can you share db? what platform do you use?

Comment: I can reproduce this with the latest SQLite on multiple platforms. Silly test data: [mydb.bz2.bz2](http://cladisch.fastmail.net/mydb.bz2.bz2) (yes, compressed *twice*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first query orders the records first by inserting *all* of them into a sorted temporary table, and then implements the `DISTINCT` by going through them and returning only those that are not identical to the previous one.
(This can be seen in the `EXPLAIN` output shown below; the `DISTINCT` actually got converted to a `GROUP BY`, which behaves the same.)

Your second query is, in theory, identical to the first, but SQLite's query optimizer is rather simple and cannot prove that this conversion would be safe (as explained in the [subquery flattening documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening)).
Therefore, it is implemented by doing the `DISTINCT` first, by inserting only any non-duplicates into a temporary table, and then doing the `ORDER BY` with a second temporary table.
This second step is completely superfluous because the first temp table was already sorted, but this happens to be faster for your data anyway because you have so many duplicates that are never stored in either temp table.

In theory, your first query could be faster, because SQLite has already recognized that the `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` clauses can be implemented with the *same* sorted temporary table.
In practice, however, SQLite it is not smart enough to remember that the `DISTINCT` implies that duplicates do not need to be stored in the temp table.
(This particular optimization might be added to SQLite if you ask nicely on the [mailing list](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/sqlite-users).)

---

```
$ sqlite3 mydb 
sqlite> .explain
sqlite> explain SELECT DISTINCT acolumn FROM atable ORDER BY acolumn;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Trace          0     0     0                    00               
1     SorterOpen     1     2     0     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
2     Integer        0     3     0                    00  clear abort flag
3     Integer        0     2     0                    00  indicate accumulator empty
4     Null           0     6     6                    00               
5     Gosub          5     37    0                    00               
6     Goto           0     40    0                    00               
7     OpenRead       0     2     0     1              00  atable       
8     Rewind         0     14    0                    00               
9     Column         0     0     8                    00  atable.acolumn
10    Sequence       1     9     0                    00               
11    MakeRecord     8     2     10                   00               
12    SorterInsert   1     10    0                    00               
13    Next           0     9     0                    01               
14    Close          0     0     0                    00               
15    OpenPseudo     2     10    2                    00               
16    SorterSort     1     39    0                    00  GROUP BY sort
17    SorterData     1     10    0                    00               
18    Column         2     0     7                    20               
19    Compare        6     7     1     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
20    Jump           21    25    21                   00               
21    Move           7     6     0                    00               
22    Gosub          4     32    0                    00  output one row
23    IfPos          3     39    0                    00  check abort flag
24    Gosub          5     37    0                    00  reset accumulator
25    Column         2     0     1                    00               
26    Integer        1     2     0                    00  indicate data in accumulator
27    SorterNext     1     17    0                    00               
28    Gosub          4     32    0                    00  output final row
29    Goto           0     39    0                    00               
30    Integer        1     3     0                    00  set abort flag
31    Return         4     0     0                    00               
32    IfPos          2     34    0                    00  Groupby result generator entry point
33    Return         4     0     0                    00               
34    Copy           1     11    0                    00               
35    ResultRow      11    1     0                    00               
36    Return         4     0     0                    00  end groupby result generator
37    Null           0     1     0                    00               
38    Return         5     0     0                    00               
39    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
40    Transaction    0     0     0                    00               
41    VerifyCookie   0     2     0                    00               
42    TableLock      0     2     0     atable         00               
43    Goto           0     7     0                    00
```

```
sqlite> explain SELECT acolumn FROM (SELECT DISTINCT acolumn FROM atable) ORDER BY acolumn;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Trace          0     0     0                    00               
1     Goto           0     39    0                    00               
2     Goto           0     17    0                    00               
3     OpenPseudo     0     3     1                    01  coroutine for sqlite_subquery_DA7480_
4     Integer        0     2     0                    01               
5     OpenEphemeral  2     0     0     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  08               
6     OpenRead       1     2     0     1              00  atable       
7     Rewind         1     14    0                    00               
8     Column         1     0     3                    00  atable.acolumn
9     Found          2     13    3     1              00               
10    MakeRecord     3     1     4                    00               
11    IdxInsert      2     4     0                    00               
12    Yield          1     0     0                    00               
13    Next           1     8     0                    01               
14    Close          1     0     0                    00               
15    Integer        1     2     0                    00               
16    Yield          1     0     0                    00  end sqlite_subquery_DA7480_
17    SorterOpen     3     3     0     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
18    Integer        2     1     0                    00               
19    Yield          1     0     0                    00  next row of co-routine sqlite_subquery_DA7480_
20    If             2     29    0                    00               
21    Column         0     0     5                    00  sqlite_subquery_DA7480_.acolumn
22    MakeRecord     5     1     6                    00               
23    Column         0     0     7                    00  sqlite_subquery_DA7480_.acolumn
24    Sequence       3     8     0                    00               
25    Move           6     9     0                    00               
26    MakeRecord     7     3     10                   00               
27    SorterInsert   3     10    0                    00               
28    Goto           0     19    0                    00               
29    OpenPseudo     4     6     1                    00               
30    OpenPseudo     5     11    3                    00               
31    SorterSort     3     37    0                    00               
32    SorterData     3     11    0                    00               
33    Column         5     2     6                    20               
34    Column         4     0     5                    20               
35    ResultRow      5     1     0                    00               
36    SorterNext     3     32    0                    00               
37    Close          4     0     0                    00               
38    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
39    Transaction    0     0     0                    00               
40    VerifyCookie   0     2     0                    00               
41    TableLock      0     2     0     atable         00               
42    Goto           0     2     0                    00
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside most DBMS, SQL statements are translated into [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) and then structured in an expression tree.
The dbms then uses heuristics to optimise queries. One of the main heuristics is "[Perform selection early](http://de.slideshare.net/koolkampus/ch14)" (p.46). I suppose the sqlite query planner does this as well, hence the differences in execution time.

Since the result of the subquery is much smaller (~50 rows opposed to 4.5 million), sorting, at the end of the expression tree, happens much faster. (Plain) Selecting isn't a very expensive process, running operations on a multitude of results is indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this must be because the order operation and distinct operations must be implemented more efficiently when separated by the subselect - which is effectively a simpler way to say way alexdeloy is saying.

This experiment is not complete.  Please also run the following:

```
% echo "SELECT acolumn FROM (SELECT DISTINCT acolumn FROM atable ORDER BY acolumn) ;" | time sqlite3 mydb
```

Tell me if this takes longer than the other two on average and thanks.

Comment: Takes about the same amount of time as the first query above.

Comment: I expect the plan will look the same too. if so, then I guess that supports the theory that performing the distinct operation on the temporary b-tree then performing the sort on the final b-tree is more efficient in sqllite.  To really know for sure, it might take a debugger.